# Find Duplicate Object in List and Add Parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find duplicate objects in a list of objects and add new parameters to the duplicate one.

Below snipped code is what I implemented so far. The problem is that it adds desired parameters to every object in the list.

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
  }
];

const newList = list.reduce(
  (unique, item) => (unique.includes(item) ? unique : [...unique, {
    ...item,
    duplicated: true,
    name: `${item.name}_${item.id}`
  }]), []
);

console.log(newList);
```

Since there are two duplicate objects by `id`, the duplicated one should have `duplicated` and new `name` parameters. What part is wrong in my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using **findIndex** method:

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
  }
];

const newList = list.reduce(
  (unique, item) => (unique.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id) > -1 ? [...unique, {
    ...item,
    duplicated: true,
    name: `${item.name}_${item.id}`
  }] : [...unique, item]), []);

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried `unique.find()` and failed. I should have tried `.findIndex`... Thanks once again.

Comment: You can replace ```findIndex(...) > -1``` with ```some```

Answer (score 0):

It can be written simply:

```js
const
    list = [
        { id: 1, name: 'test1' }, 
        { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'test3' },
        { id: 2, name: 'test2' }
    ],
    uniqueList = list.reduce((arr, { id, name }) =>
        arr.concat({
            id,
            name,
            ...arr.some(item => id === item.id) && { duplicate: true, name: `${name}_${id}` }
        }), []);

console.log(uniqueList);
```

The problem was that when you called `includes` you were actually looking for an object whose pointer exists in the array.
In order to find an object which has property are the same as a requested property, you have no choice but to use functions such as `some` or `every` that is different from `includes` - you can send them a callback and not just an object.